# Conversion of a 'for' loop with an increment of 25 from C to MATLAB

Tags: c, matlab, for-loop

I have a `for` loop written in C:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=25)
```

How can I convert it to MATLAB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i+=25)
```

can be converted to MATLAB for loop in this way:

```
>> for i = [0:25:1000]
   # Code
   end
```

Comment: I think you mean `for i`, not just `i`. And you don't need the `[]` surrounding the colon expression.

Comment: -1 This **does not** give the right answer: `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=25)` yields the numbers `0 25 50 ... 950 975` where as `i = 0:25:1000` yields `0 25 50 ... 950 975 1000`. If `i < 1000;` were replaced with `i <= 1000;` or if `i = 0:25:975` was used then the output would match.

Comment: Also note that `i=[0:25:1000]` actually means something different than `i=0:25:1000` - in the first case, you are actually preallocating memory to store the vector `0:25:1000`. This might not matter for this  loop, but compare to `i=1:inf` and `i=[1:inf]`.

Answer (score 10):

The MATLAB [for loop syntax](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/for.html) is

```
for i = values
    program statements
      :
end
```

where `values` is one of

- `start:end`
- `start:step:end`, or
- an array of values.

The form `start:end` assumes a step of `1`, whereas you want a step (or increment) of 25, so use the second form. From your question, `for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=25)` generates a list of the numbers `0 25 50 ... 950 975`, i.e. it does not include `1000` (notice the `i < 1000;` in the `for` loop), so we can't use `end=1000` in out MATLAB syntax. Instead use `end = 1000-25  = 975`:

```
for i = 0:25:975
    program statements
      :
end
```

will yield the same values of `i` as the C equivalent.

**Note**: see my comment on Mithun Sasidharan's answer. His answer yields different numbers for the C and MATLAB for loops (and he seems to have dropped the `for` from his MATLAB answer). His answer gives `0 25 50 ... 950 975` for the C loop and `0 25 50 ... 950 975 1000` for his MATLAB code.

**Edit**: Aashish Thite's answer raises an important point about for loops and array indexing which differs between C and MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use 'i' as an index for scanning through an array, `for i=0:25:1000` will not work. The index of the first element in an array of matlab is 1. So use  `for i=1:25:1000`