# What's the meaning of matlab code of data(1:8:end)

Tags: matlab

I am new in Matlab, see a code as below,
[a]= complex(data(1:8:end), data(2:8:end)); then could anyone tell me what's 1:8:end mean here?
Base on my understanding, 1 is the 1st line, 8 is the 8th column, then what's the end mean?
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html#mw_9fea271b-869f-483f-b233-59caea76daf3

Comment: Here is a short introduction to indexing in MATLAB: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: 1:8:end means start the beginning and get the data until the end, but with interval = 8

Comment: Note: the "duplicate" post link points to a question and answer that doesn't address the question posed here. This question is about the role of "1:8" and "end", while the supposed duplicate is only about the role of "end" and does not address the role of the stride/interval. A better duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473799/conversion-of-a-for-loop-with-an-increment-of-25-from-c-to-matlab